# Sankey diagram highlighting the orgigin of sources

Tags: plotly, data-visualization, visualization, sankey-diagram

I am trying to make a **sankey diagram**, preferably with Python. The ones that come closest to what I want to do are with plotly, but I am stuck with the following.

Let's take the examples on the [plotly documentation page](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/). When you hoover over a block (one of the vertical lines) you can see the stuff flowing in and out highlighted in dark. But that highlighting stops at the next (or previous) block, and I would want to know from which of the sources of that block the ones in the selected block originate from. So, basically, when I select one node, and track all that comes in all the way to the very sources and final targets of the sankey diagram. I do not see an option in this, or any other sankey diagram plotting package.

The problem relates to the way most packages build up their diagram, basically only storing the flows with source, target and volume, hence loosing the information of the full flow. In most circumstances I guess that flow is well known. This data set can be e.g. compiled from what visitors on a website do and in uch it a case it takes wrangling and aggregating the data in order to get to the source/target/volume data and the connection between the different flows is gone, which is too bad...

Does anybody have a clue, other than going for process mining software? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't, that's the point....